# how to do queryOne with go-pg properly?

Tags: postgresql, go, go-pg

I want to `queryOne` using `go-pg` that only return one row to an object only not array.

this is my simple code :

```
var reportMessage *ReportMessage
    _, err := db.Model((*ReportMessage)(nil)).QueryOne(&reportMessage, `
    SELECT 
        SUM(total_order) total_order,
        SUM(total_message) total_message,
        SUM(hsm_message) hsm_message ,
        SUM(outbound_message) outbound_message ,
        SUM(inbound_message) inbound_message ,
        SUM(total_order_amount) total_order_amount 
        FROM report_message rm WHERE seller_id =? and "date" between ? and ?;

    `, sellerID, dateStart, dateEnd)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return reportMessage, nil
```

```
type ReportMessage struct {
    ID               string    `json:"id"`
    SellerID         string    `json:"seller_id"`
    TotalOrder       int       `json:"total_order"`
    Date             time.Time `json:"date"`
    HsmMessage       int       `json:"hsm_message"`
    TotalMessage     int       `json:"total_message"`
    OutboundMessage  int       `json:"outbound_message"`
    InboundMessage   int       `json:"inbound_message"`
    TotalOrderAmount float32   `json:"total_order_amount"`
}
```

I wish it will return reportMessage only not an array.

and this is my error :

```
json: cannot unmarshal number into Go value of type models.ReportMessage
```

how to query only one row and return it to object not array?

Comment: What part of the error message is confusing you?  You cannot unmarshal a number into a Go value of type `models.ReportMessage`.  Since you haven't included your full code, we cannot tell you _which_ number you're trying to unmarshal into that type, but the error makes it clear that one of your numeric columns is trying to be unmarshaled into that type.

Comment: honestly this is the full code, okay i will add the struct. if I use `query` and change to array, it work. but in this condition I want to query only one and return it in object

Comment: @yozawiratama are you certain the problem is with the query? The error is coming from the encoding/json package and unless go-pg is itself, under the hood, attempting to unmarshal some json into the model then it makes no sense that the error would be caused by the provided code.

Comment: @yozawiratama although i don't think the way you initialize the model would cause a problem, maybe try to properly initialize it and then pass in a pointer to the struct rather than a pointer to a `nil` pointer which is what you're doing right now. i.e. `mesg := new(ReportMessage)` and then `db.Model(...).QueryOne(mesg, ...` note `mesg` is already a pointer, there's no need to pass in `&mesg` to go-pg.

Comment: @mkopriva, really this is a solution, why dont you create it be an answer?

Comment: @yozawiratama my second comment? or the first?

Comment: @mkopriva your second comment, thanks dude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize an instance of the model and pass a pointer to that instance rather than passing a pointer to an uninitialized nil pointer of the model.

```
reportMessage := new(ReportMessage)
_, err := db.Model((*ReportMessage)(nil)).QueryOne(reportMessage, `
SELECT 
    SUM(total_order) total_order,
    SUM(total_message) total_message,
    SUM(hsm_message) hsm_message ,
    SUM(outbound_message) outbound_message ,
    SUM(inbound_message) inbound_message ,
    SUM(total_order_amount) total_order_amount 
    FROM report_message rm WHERE seller_id =? and "date" between ? and ?;

`, sellerID, dateStart, dateEnd)

if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

return reportMessage, nil
```